Graddle Issue : incompatible Java 21.0.3 and Gradle 7.1.1
when running project in android studio, it show error like this :
Your build is currently configured to use incompatible Java 21.0.3 and Gradle 7.1.1. Cannot sync the project. We recommend upgrading to Gradle version 8.9. The minimum compatible Gradle version is 8.5. The maximum compatible Gradle JVM version is 16.
i already trying update to Gradle version is 8.5 is didnt works.
could you help me?
my expected my project run well

Go to Setting -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle.
Try to set Gradle JDK version 17
